# Seaborn plots in alphabetical order, not in dataframe order

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, line-plot

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

when I want to plot last two columns:

```
sns.lineplot(ax=ax2, x="ay", y="özel_2021",  data=okul_2021,
         color="g",label='özel okul',linewidth=3)

sns.lineplot(ax=ax2, x="ay", y="devlet_2021", data=okul_2021,
         color="r",label='devlet okulu',linewidth=3)
```

[image]

It plots not in the order in the dataframe but in alphabetical order. How can I fix this?

Full code is here:

[image]

Comment: Please never upload code as image. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You might try `sns.plot(....., order=okul_201['ay'])` to force a given order on the x-values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved when I add sort=False;

```
sns.lineplot(x="ay", y="özel_2021",  data=okul_2021,
         color="g",label='özel okul',linewidth=3,sort=False)

sns.lineplot(x="ay", y="devlet_2021", data=okul_2021,
         color="r",label='devlet okulu',linewidth=3,sort=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to test this, but I think you will need to set your column `ay` as a [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) column:

```py
okul_2021["ay"] = pd.to_datetime(okul_2021["ay"], format="%B")
```

Here the `%B` means 'month as locale’s full name'